# Combine 2 object of same model Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

Is there any way to combine/merge 2+ objects of the same model to 1 with total values of all field.

I mean like `Author.objects.annotate(Sum('book__pages'))` but for all fields in model.

1 object - `{'user':2, 'events':20, 'time': 233}`

2 object - `{'user':2, 'events':10, 'time': 400}`

need total - `{'user':2, 'events':30, 'time': 633}`

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `values()` and then `annotate()`.

```
MyModel.objects.values('user').annotate(
    total_events=Sum('events'),
    total_time=Sum('time'),
)
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#values) for more info.

Comment: is this the only way to count total values? Not the best one for me, as i have mannualyy type every value from the model.

Comment: If you don’t want to type out the fields, you could introspect the model to create a dict `kwargs={'total_events': Sum('events'), ...}`, then call `.annotate(**kwargs)`.

Comment: so i can create `kwargs ={'total_field_name': Sum('field_name'), ... +12 fields} ` and then call on model query set `.annotate(**kwargs)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting.

Comment: And if you don't want to hardcode the field names, you can introspect the model using the [Meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/).